# PayuMoney Integration in Android : Some error occured! Try again

Tags: android, payment-gateway, payumoney

I'm integrating payuMoney (not payu biz) in my android application. I followed [this](https://www.payumoney.com/payment-gateway-integration-guide.html) official documentation of PayuMoney. I have changed merchant key, merchant id and url of hash generation of my server in [this](https://github.com/payu-intrepos/PayUMoney-Android-SDK/blob/master/app/src/main/java/payumoney/payu/com/payumoneysdkapp/MyActivity.java) sample app. Then it is taking me to PayuMoney sdk screen where I can login/signup. But it is showing the toast message **'Some error occured! Try again'** once I login with my credentials. Is there anything else that I'm missing? Please guide me.

Comment: You need to better check with payment gateway support.

Comment: Hey Did you solved the issue ?? I am facing the same please comment.

Comment: Any one found solution for this issue? I am facing same right now..

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue

Comment: Hello did u find a solution?? If yes, please add answer.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you might not have activated your account on PayUMoney. Try contacting the customer service and get your account activatied. The error will be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when **server generated hash** not equal to **payUmoney generated hash** so payUmoney don't allow payments

also, shows blank screen after login

to fix it generate a hash like this formate

`String hashSequence=KEY+"|"+txn+"|"+amount+"|"+productinfo+"|"+firstname+"|"+email+"|"+UDF1+"|"+UDF2+"|"+UDF3+"|"+UDF4+"|"+UDF5+"|"+SALT;`